# Asp.net WebApi method instead of AngularJs Service

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have written Angularjs service as shown below.It retrieves data from the 3rd party service.It's working fine.

Now I have a requirement to write a WebApi method for the same.The reason for that is, we can consume that service from various types of applications.i.e. desktop, web and mobile.How can I implement such a service?

**AngulaJS service:**

```
(function () {
    appModule.service('getPropertyDetailsByUsingApiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.propertyDetails = function (token, number, street, county, zip) {
            var endpointUrl = 'http://myaddress.com/api/AddressMatcher?Token=';
            var url = endpointUrl + token + '&Number=' + number + '&Street=' + street + '&County=' + county + '&Zip=' + zip;

            return $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                var result = data;
                if (result.data[0].Status == 'OK') {
                    return $http.get(endpointUrl + token + '&Apn=' + result.data[0].Result[0].APN + '&County=' + county)
                        .then(function (finalData) {
                            return finalData;
                        });
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        };
    }
    ]);
})();
```

**WebApi method :**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<MyModelDto> GetPropertyDetailsByUsingApiService()
    {
        //I would like to have a help here to implement it

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting in output? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I can manage the output.I just need to know how to call the above mentioned 3rd party services within the web API. @Pavvy

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for [HttpClient.GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync.aspx).

For example,

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://...");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiDetails.BaseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiDetails.RequestUrl, obj).Result;                
        }
```